# Can't make selection (can't filter) of collection while processing e-mails

Tags: email, powershell, com, outlook, powershell-4.0

I want to create some automation of e-mail processing.

I followed [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx) and it worked fine. Summary, I got a collection of e-mails of one of my mailbox, however I can't filter them (can't provide `where` method). I can use `foreach` operator, but it seems to me it's not a best idea (like using cursor functionality in order to filter tables value in SQL instead of using 'where' option).

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)

$mailsInEventFolder = $inbox.Folders.Item('Events').Items
```

By implementing the last command I'm getting collection of my e-mails (collection of `System.MarshalByRefObject`). Common methods for common collection like `where{$_ -eq ...}` are not working here.

If I try `where` method, I'm getting an error message "MethodNotFound". Also I can't get list of all methods for this collection by using `Get-Member` command, because it gives me methods of e-mail object and I need methods of collection-object.

I know that for this collection I can use the following:

- `$mailsInEventFolder.Item(int32)`
- `$mailsInEventFolder.Item(string)`
- `$mailsInEventFolder.Count`
- `$mailsInEventFolder.Add(obj)`
- `$mailsInEventFolder.Remove(int32)`

I wasted a lot of time while searching this correct object collection in documentation, however I didn't succeed.

Please give me advice how to filter my e-mail by value of some property of e-mail object without using `foreach`. Or please give me correct reference to description of this collection object.

Comment: I'm using desktop outlook v.2013. My OS Windows 7. Powershell v.4.0. Net framework 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Items.Find/FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Items.Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869597.aspx).
Do not loop through the items in a folder looking for a match (that is what you code does) - each item will need to be opened. Let the store provider do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid :(

What I was looking for is:

```
$mailsInEventFolder | ? {$_.SenderName -eq 'SomeName'}
```

Sorry for you time.

Comment: don't use this answer!

Answer (score 0):

my previous answer worked fine, but it was very slow while processing 500+ emails. So i found another solution: 
Items.Restrict("[SentOn]>'21/12/2015 00:01'")

restrict option allow to use a filter option ([senton] - property of email object). And it's a hundred times faster!

here's some documentation about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220369(v=office.12).aspx
(pls, be aware not everything in this article works for PS).

U're welcome :)